# getting error while running this command mahout trainnb -i path_to/train-vectors -el -li path_to/labelindex -o path_to/model -ow -c

Tags: linux, hadoop, hdfs, mahout

[image]

see the attached image.I am using mahout locally. I have converted sequence file to sparse vectors and I have also split the set into two sets: a training set and a testing set:

```
mahout split -i tweets-vectors/tfidf-vectors --trainingOutput train-vectors --testOutput test-vectors --randomSelectionPct 40 --overwrite --sequenceFiles -xm sequential.
```

getting an error while running this command `mahout trainnb -i train-vectors -el -li labelindex -o model -ow -c`

Answer (score 1):

That `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` is usually due to your having the wrong number of fields in a record or vector. This can be caused by improper parsing (wrong delimiter, stray commas in a comma-separated file, etc.) or another issue with the fields you're expecting being in the wrong place.

Comment: @shah, It looks like your label index only has a single class. As well, FYI, while the old Mahout-MapReduce is still available, it has been deprecated and is no longer supported.  Mahout now supports a [Spark Naive Bayes](http://mahout.apache.org/docs/latest/tutorials/samsara/spark-naive-bayes.html).  The ASF has a Slack channel #Mahout.  All one has to do send an email to dev@mahout.apache.org and ask for an Invite to join.  There are many community members available.

Comment: I am following this procedure provided in this below link .https://chimpler.wordpress.com/2013/03/13/using-the-mahout-naive-bayes-classifier-to-automatically-classify-twitter-messages/
if you have any alternate way please provide me. I really need it

Comment: @akm. This is the link I was following. Everything worked fine. I am only getting the error on this part "mahout trainnb -i train-vectors -el -li labelindex -o model -ow -c" and i do not know why?
https://chimpler.wordpress.com/2013/03/13/using-the-mahout-naive-bayes-classifier-to-automatically-classify-twitter-messages/